# How to know when a user is signed in

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to implement a Cart service using Node.js and SQL. I have two carts tables, one for guests (guestCart) and the other when a user is signed in (memberCart). The implementation looks like this:

```
if(user not signed in){
  Add item to guestCart
}else{
  Add item to memberCart
}
```

I am using passport.js for authentication. My question is: How do I check that a user has been signed in? When a user is signed in, what condition is TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether a user is logged in by checking req.user. If the user is logged in, req.user should be an object containing detailed information about the user. If the user is not logged in, req.user could be undefined.

```
if(req.user){
  // user login add to memberCart
}else{
  // don't login add to guestCart
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this different from req.isAuthenticated?